# Using a model's ID as a default for another field

Tags: django, django-models

Or can you do this?

This won't necessarily be the end result model (as it kinda illogical irl), but whilst creating this model what I'd like to do is have the default value of the two parents of a person be the person itself, and so use it's own ID as the parent reference.

At this point the AutoField for the ID is fine. Unless I need to change it to facilitate what I'm looking to do.

Understandably I'll get the 'self' error migrating the below, but it helps describe my example:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    dtob = models.DateTimeField(blank=False, verbose_name="Date of birth", default=datetime.now)
    dtod = models.DateTimeField(blank=False, verbose_name="Date of death", default=datetime.now)
    creationdate = models.DateTimeField(blank=False, verbose_name="Creation date", default=datetime.now)
    BLOOD_TYPE_CHOICES=(
        ('O+', 'O Positive'),
        ('O-', 'O Negative'),
        ('A+', 'A Positive'),
        ('A-', 'A Negative'),
        ('B+', 'B Positive'),
        ('B-', 'B Negative'),
        ('AB+', 'AB Positive'),
        ('AB-', 'AB Negative'),
    )
    bloodtype = models.CharField(blank=False, verbose_name="Blood type", max_length=3, choices=BLOOD_TYPE_CHOICES, default='O+')
    parentA = models.IntegerField(blank=False, verbose_name="Parent A", default=self.id)
    parentB = models.IntegerFiled(blank=False, verbose_name="Parent B", default=self.id)
```

All help and comments appreciated.

Comment: You can override the save() to do that. Once you save you can update the parents ids with self.id and save again.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to do this using `default`. Those defaults are computed in Python, before the data is sent to the database and the `id` is generated.

One way to do it would be to use a database trigger, but you can do basically the same thing in Django by overriding `save()` or handling the [`post_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-save) signal, since at that point the instance's `id` will have been generated. Here's an example of the latter:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=Person)
def populate_parents(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        instance.parentA = instance.id
        instance.parentB = instance.id
        instance.save()
```

Comment: That's more or less what I figured, it would be akin to asking it to use an imaginary number that doesn't exist yet as a default. With some of the nice Django trickery I've come across, I thought it might be worth asking :)
At a save() point I can do something else, thanks both for the input.